# How to parse EXTREMELY fuzzy dates?

Tags: python-3.x, date, fuzzy-comparison

I have web scraped data in a column of a pandas dataframe that represents when different pieces of art were created. This data was entered in as strings by various people in many many different formats. Some examples:

- `1998`
- `circa 1995`
- `c. 2003-5`
- `March 2, 1904`
- `1st quarter of 19th century`
- `19th to 20th century`
- `ca. late 19th and early 20th Century`
- `BCE 500`
- `206 BCE-240 CE`
- `1995-99`
- `designed 1950, produced 1969`
- `designed 1935, produced circa 1946-1968`
- `1990; and 1989`
- `1975/97`
- `618-907 CE`
- `2001; 2006 and 2008`
- `1937-42/48`
- `no date`
- `n.d.`
- `mid 1900s`
- `late 1940's`

I've spent a couple days writing a long transformer class that attempts to handle every combination in my current dataset, which is semi-successful, but I figured this must be something people have done in the past.

So does there exist any way in Python to handle date information that is extremely fuzzy in this way?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says  in very clear language that you cannot ask for software library recommendations here. In addition, asking what is *the best* is by definition asking for opinion, and primarily opinion-based questions are also off-topic here. You may want to refresh your understanding of the site guidelines before your next question.

Comment: Is there any way to reformat this question in a stack-acceptable way?

Comment: Not with the question you're asking. You're clearly asking for opinion-based recommendations for a software library - how could that possibly be restated to not do so? Remove all content asking for opinion and your entire final paragraph, and there is no question being asked. (Your current edit does not help. Trying to hide the recommendation request with *in Python (or possibly other)* and *point me in the right direction, library or otherwise* is clearly an attempt at subterfuge to circumvent the guidelines. Shame.

Comment: You **cannot ask for a software library recommendation**, whether you phrase it as *best* or not. Please read the [help/on-topic] I previously linked, in particular the section with the numbered list, **specifically** item #4 in that list.

Comment: I've edited my post so that it no longer asks for a library recommendation in any way.

Comment: I've voted to reopen based on that edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing is categorically known as "Natural Language Parsing", or NLP.

Googling for Python NLP Date Parsing libraries yields several results.  You should do that, and evaluate them for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, knowing to search for NLP has given me a start, although it's beginning to seem that my test cases are a bit much for what is out there currently.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to think about a common type, model, or schema that you might map these things *to*.  For example, what would be a reasonable representation of "late 1940's"?  A `datetime` certainly doesn't seem to fit.